Sitecore XMC latest metadata.js script doesn't support monorepo?
I've done this multiple times with Headless Sitecore Solutions which are not XMCloud however it appears that within the latest XMCloud version there are some additional scripts and components that get created which appear to have hard-coded references to a local /node_modules directory which results in an error when trying to configure monorepo/npm workspaces where we have a single node_modules folder at the workspace level rather than each jss application having it's own.
The files in question are
/scripts/generate-metadata.ts
which calls
node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-dev-tools/dist/cjs/templating/metadata.js
and within this there is a getMetadata() function which parses the node_modules folder in the logic.
The error I get is

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\git\sitecore-xmcloud\src\rendering\apps\public-website\node_modules

If I create an empty node_modules folder in each head it will get past this error however the second part to this is that then there are some SXA components that ship OOTB using Font-Awesome which also seem to "require" a local node_modules version of the font-awesome package. If I copy that into each site (we have 4 sites/heads) they will run but it kind of defeats the purpose of Mono-Repo...

I have a support ticket open, but the two changes I needed to make to the OOTB Sitecore app solution were as follows:

Looking at the new getMetaData() call, you can locate the file itself here: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/packages/sitecore-jss-dev-tools/src/templating/metadata.ts where we can see the references to a local node_modules directory in the sitecore-jss-dev-tools library. I've copied this into the the script file in the app and updated it to look for node_modules where it actually resides in our mono-repo set up which is ../../node_modules (for me). It's a temporary workaround while I wait to hear form support but I suspect this is likely the solve regardless.

The OOTB SXA comps referencing Font Awesome needed to have the new config updated located here: /src/lib/next-config/plugins/sass.js within this file there are some settings to define location for node_mdules where again we need to update to point to the node_modules folder.  Note: this isn't a problem and fine as we can update as required so it's only the first item that really needed some intervention :)



From the Support team who are all over it :)
Please use the JSS-3466 as a reference number. For more information of the reference number: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0853187
